# Find substrings of a particular length/ format in Java

Tags: java, string, csv, substring, filenames

I have a program in Java that has a string array of filenames and cycles through them performing certain changes. The input filenames all have a similar but not exactly the same format:

ABC_0123_08122013_XXX.csv

0123 being an ID number, 08122013 being a date. This file name is stored as a string and I want to be able to pick the ID and date out of it and store them as separate strings. The date and ID number are different for each file so I need to search by substring length I guess.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What about splitting the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use String `split` method, as below :

```
    String fileName = "ABC_0123_08122013_XXX.csv";
    String split[] = fileName.split("_");

    System.out.println("The ID is "+split[1]);
    System.out.println("The Date is "+split[2]);
```